# Django app should redirect to same IP but different port

Tags: django, redirect

Have a Django running on https port (443). When user access https://hostname/newAPP, I want Django to redirect to https://hostname:port.

I tried the following line in urlpatterns in the urls.py, but could not get the result.

`url(r'^newAPP$', RedirectView.as_view(url=':8000', permanent=True), name='NewApp')`

Actually it is getting redirected, but to a wrongly formed url "https:hostname/:8000". Note the "**:**" is placed after the "**/**".

The server has multiple IPs/hostnames so hard coding the IP/hostname is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your example doesn't work because you are redirecting after the localhost:2000/,  you can create a view to redirect to another domain using something like:

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^newAPP', views.redirect, {'var': 2000}),
url(r'^anotherAPP', views.redirect, {'var': 3000}), #Of course you can use this view for more than one app
```

and in your views:

```
def redirect(request, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('https://localhost:%s' % kwargs.get('var'))
```

if you don't like this way, you can use the server. The next example is for nginx:

```
server {
    . . .
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    rewrite ^/newAPP$ https://localhost:2000 permanent;
    rewrite ^/anotherAPP$ https://localhost:3000 permanent;
    . . .
}
```

More information about [nginx redirects](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-nginx) . Tell me if that helped you

Comment: It works for the port redirection....but hard coding the IP/hostname is not an option as the server has multiple IP addresses. It would be nice if there is solution to avoid mentioning localhost/ip/hostname in views.

Comment: Then just add the full domain in the variable var and cut all inside the redirect except var

Answer (score 1):

In your base `urls.py` file you could add the following to create a view that redirects to a different port on the same ip.

I haven't tested this code extensively but it works for me for now. I'd appreciate if anyone has thoughts on redirecting to a different port robustly.

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def get_new_url(request):
    # Specify the port number, you could get this dynamically
    # through a config file or something if you wish
    new_port = '5000'

    # `request.get_host()` gives us {hostname}:{port}
    # we split this by colon to just obtain the hostname
    hostname = request.get_host().split(':')[0]
    # Construct the new url to redirect to
    url = 'http://' + hostname + ':' + new_port + '/'
    return redirect(url)

urlpatterns = [
    # Some other paths
    path('something/', views.some_view, name='something')
    # ...
    # ...

    # Add your redirect
    path('newAPP/', get_new_url, name='newapp'),

]
```

The function `get_new_url()` could live in a views.py file if you'd like. Just make sure you import it before referencing it in your `urlconf`.